# Prove that $h(D)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a continuous function and suppose $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e.  $\overline{D}=\mathbb{R}$ ). Prove that $h(D)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

This is what I was thinking...

Given $h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $D$ is dense then $\overline{D}=\mathbb{R}$. To show $h(D)$ is also dense, we have to prove $x\in h(n)$, $y$ is a limit point of $h(D)$ where $y= h(n)$, $\forall n \in D$. Since $h$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $h(p) \in N_{\epsilon}h(n)$ where $p \in N_{\delta}(n)$. Now $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore every neighborhood around $x$ intersects $D$ and there is a  $p \in D$ such that $d(p,n,)< \delta \Rightarrow \delta(h(p), h(n)) < \epsilon$.  Therefore, $N_{\epsilon}(h(n))$ intersects $h(D)$. So, $h(D)$ is dense.

Would this be the correct proof?

Comment: I think you meant if $h$ is ONTO, and continuous...   then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: what happen if $h$ is the constant function ?

Comment: Could you explain? I don't understand how that helps me to fix my proof. What part(s) of my proof in incorrect and should be fixed?